# How to modify the power low to 5V and fit this circuit?

Tags: pwm

[image]

This circuit able convert PWM input signal to 0-10 DC output.
But I only have +5V power supply and I just only need 0-4.5V DC output.
How to amend more suitable ?

Comment: Yep, that's a random internet circuit...

Comment: If you turn the pot (R2) to the minimum then the gain will be 1. So you'll have 0-5V output. That's it.

Comment: You won't get 4.5V out of an LM358 loaded with 10K. Use a rail-to-rail in/out amplifier only. Just take the output from the A amplifier and throw the other half of the dual in the trash bin.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany, I do think it's good advice to use a more modern and capable op-amp. But I don't understand your comment that an LM358 would struggle to drive 4.5V into 10K off a 12V rail - what makes you say that? I'd used them a fair bit with no problems at all. Thanks :-)

Comment: @TonyM It's essentially a voltage follower so both the output range and the input common mode range must include 4.5V. The LM358 input is good for 3.5V with a 5V supply (3.0V over temperature, the number you should be using). The high-level output voltage with a 5V supply and 10K load will get to 3.5V min with (see the [TI datasheet Voh spec](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/61/46/87/01/98/ed/44/c5/CD00000464.pdf/files/CD00000464.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00000464.pdf)) but that's **only** at 25°C, so again probably you should use 3.0V.

Comment: @TonyM This is not a 'problem', just a limitation of this fabulously cheap and versatile chip. If you add a pullup resistor it's  possible to coax the output closer to the positive rail, but that does nothing for the input and will prevent the output from getting close to the negative rail, so a net loss in my books. Dividing the inputs will deal with the common mode range so you could fiddle with it and get it to sort of work, but there are better RRIO CMOS parts for << $1 these days and that would have a few advantages such as allowing the 10uF to be reduced by increasing the 4K7.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany, thanks for your good answer. Can I check that you saw the OP's supply is 12V, not 5V? I originally thought you were imagining a 5V rail. You're spot on about the restricted output swing. The plentiful and cheap LM324 quad op-amp was similar, with a 1.5V ceiling under the rail.

Comment: @TonyM Yeah, that "I only have +5V power supply" was key.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany, ah, yes...that's me being a complete idiot and not reading the words in the question, then :-)

Comment: Yes, the distressed is only have +5V power supply in my environment. when I try to modify the power from +12V low down to +5V, the Vout form 10.495V low to remaining 38.816mv (PWM IN input 1Khz,5Vpp,duty cycle 99) >< . Who can help me ?